# playwright - issue DELETE request

Tags: playwright

When I test my angular app I need to reset some server data, so I tried to make an HTTP DELETE request before each test:

```
   test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
      const reply = await page.evaluate(async () => {
         return await fetch("https://localhost:44302/api/cleanup", { method: "DELETE" });
      });
      jsome(reply);
   });
```

and I get the following error:

> page.evaluate: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Failed to fetch

How can I do this before running my tests with Playwright?

Comment: It probably is not a problem with Playwright but with fetch itself. Does it work if you manually run this command in console? Do you have valid SSL certificate for this localhost domain?

Comment: I tried it with Postman - no problem

Comment: Yes, it may work with Postman but that is not the answer to any of my questions. I suspect fetch request fails because the localhost API endpoint does not a valid SSL certificate and you query it via HTTPS.